# Using SSL on Drupal site - domain not secure

Tags: ssl, https, drupal, drupal-7

My hosting company has implemented SSL on my account. It is a multi-site Drupal setup and the sites that are accessed directly via my domain registrar (Hover) are working correctly but one site doesn't ... the problem for that site appears to be that I forward that domain to FastMail to manage some email and from there I forward the domain to the web host. I get the domain name is not secure and this message: NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
Does anyone know how to change the configuration?

Comment: Check if domain is in list which used for generate certification, also if you have a resource loaded in HTTP in your content , you can't have HTTPS certification to green .

Comment: It appears that the certificate is not considered valid if it is used by a 3rd party.  I followed the instructions on FastMail but I can't get them to work (yet).

Comment: check html rendered , open network console and search if a http request is made whitout https

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback however my host service was unable to set the site to use ssl because it went via a 3rd party mail server.